# How to add external libraries in a Play2.1 scala project?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I want to use scala compiler library, and add it in Eclipse, 
but when compiling the project again using `eclipse`, the library is deleted automatically by the compilation. What's wrong with that?

So the question is: if my play project want to use scala-compiler.jar, how to add that? 
it does not work by using `build path`-> `configure build path...` in eclipse...

I also tried to put all the jar files to the `lib/` folder, but when compiling again in the server using `eclipse`, it still gives out compiling errors because of not finding the jars.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

The most failure-proof way to add it is to use Play's configuration builder, not adding it explicitly with Eclipse. To build a correct Eclipse project, use:

```
$ play
[YourProject] $ eclipse
[info] About to create Eclipse project files for your project(s).
[info] Successfully created Eclipse project files for project(s):
```

Then you can import it from Eclipse under `File/Import/General/Existing project…` (see [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/IDE) for more).

Note that Play uses sbt, which is already configured to use some version of Scala.

Comment: I think I still don't understand that how to add external libraries to the play project that has been created?  The problem is that I have already run `eclipse`, it does not add the external libraries but delete the libraries added.

Comment: Does it not pull the scala-* libraries?

Comment: Also, see if this helps: https://github.com/skyluc/SandBox/wiki/play-2.0-in-scala-ide-2.0